# Running a python file from current location to another one?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I am new in Ubuntu :) 
By using Terminal now i am on particular location and i want to run a python file that found in another location ? 
what the correct command to run this file in the current location? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a pretty good chance that this will be closed as off-topic, but all you need to do is `python path/to/your/file.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the complete file path, just:

```
python /home/user/this/is/an/example/main.py
```

If you are not sure where the file is, open a terminal window in its location and type `pwd`, this will give you the current directory